# TypeError: Cannot set property 'highlight' of undefined angular-typeahead

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add [angular-typeahead](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) to my app for search suggestion taking help from this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cMvm7Z4REuIP69Uk4Tzz?p=preview).

This is the code of app.js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','siyfion.sfTypeahead']);

myApp.factory('websitesSvc',function($http, $log, $q) {
return {
    getwebsites: function(){

        //Create a promise using promise library
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/websites/'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers,config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers,config){
                deferred.reject(status);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','websitesSvc','$timeout',
function($scope,websitesSvc,$timeout) {

$scope.searchString=null;


websitesSvc.getwebsites().then(function(websites){
 $scope.websites = websites;
}); 

$timeout(function() {
var websites = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.domain_name); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local:$scope.websites,
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
 websites.initialize();

$scope.numbersDataset = {
displayKey: 'domain_name',
 source: websites.ttAdapter()
};

// Typeahead options object
$scope.exampleOptions = {
 highlight: true
}; 
},1000);

 }
]);
```

Adding delay so that the services are executed first and then the data fetched can be passed to typeahead for search suggestions.But I am getting following errors in console [image: Console Error].
How should I change my code to debug this?

Comment: Try to remove `$timeout(function() {`

Comment: then the code in the `timeout` function will execute before `websitesSvc.getwebsites().then(function(websites){
 $scope.websites = websites;
}); `.

Comment: I don't you initialize everything in one digest cycle (in one then)?

Comment: I am beginner in angular so can you please suggest how should i edit this

Comment: Maybe like this: http://jsfiddle.net/paz4mo52/

Comment: its not working.This Plunkr passes an array http://plnkr.co/edit/cMvm7Z4REuIP69Uk4Tzz?p=preview and its working..but the thing is getting data from services and then make it work...if i use just an array it will work no problem..but when I put the   `websites.initialize();

        $scope.numbersDataset = {
            displayKey: 'domain_name',
            source: websites.ttAdapter()
        };

        // Typeahead options object
        $scope.exampleOptions = {
            highlight: true
        };` in function it gives error in console